# How add users input into TableViewController. Also please explain me, how MVC will work in this case

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller

Here is the UI. So initial view is my tableViewController, which is empty. It has a button "add" and when a user taps it the new viewController appears with textfield and button. When user tapps the button the program automatically add textfield.text to the tableviewController and also go back to it.

[image]

Here is the code of tableViewController.

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var myArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {
        cell.myLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}


}
```

And here is the code of viewController. I tried to create an object of my tableViewController and get its array and add to that array users input. After it i reload the tableView. But it doesn't work when i go back. Please help me to understand how this work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myTexfield: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


@IBAction func saveAndGoBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let myTableViewControllerObject = MyTableViewController()
    myTableViewControllerObject.myArray.append(myTexfield.text ?? "No value")
    myTableViewControllerObject.tableView.reloadData()

}


}
```

Also if somebody will be able to show me how the same thing will work with MVC that would be perfect. I mean I'm missing the model in this case and I know that it is very bad to create a connection between viewControllers to pass data.

Update()
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating `let myTableViewControllerObject = MyTableViewController()` a new instance of MyTableViewController you can't retrieve your old view. In your code you are create a new instance. Instead of that you need to get reference of your old view.

If you have used Modal presentation you can get reference of your old view by accusing `self.presentingViewController`

```
@IBAction func saveAndGoBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let myTableViewControllerObject = (self.presentingViewController as! MyTableViewController)
  myTableViewControllerObject.myArray.append(myTexfield.text ?? "No value")
  myTableViewControllerObject.tableView.reloadData()
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

N:B

If you are UINavigationController in MyTableViewController Then change code to

```
 let myTableViewControllerObject = (self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController)!.viewControllers.first as! MyTableViewController
```

Comment: How you are dismissing your presented new viewController? in saveAndGoBack

Comment: present modally from Main.storyboard. I tried and get an error that there is a nill while unwrapping

Comment: Remove present modally for going back. By doing so you are creating another instance of MyTableViewController and presenting it. This make 3 different viewControllers. Use dismiss method to go back as edited in the answer

Comment: I deleted segue from button to tableViewController and added dismiss, but I'm still getting the same error. Added a screenshot to the bottom part of my question.

Comment: ooo, yes, perfect, it worked, thank you very much...
se each time when i want to get a reference of one view, I need to use the method presentingViewController as? Where can I read about it?